# Send data from laravel 5.3 to web service with ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web-services, laravel-5.3

I want to send data with ajax jquery to a web service in laravel 5.3. my ajax code is(URL in this question is an example):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://199.166.212.50:8080/.../add",
        contentType:'application/json',
        data: {
            "requester":
            {
                "userName": "jac",
                "password": "111"
            },
            "request":
            {
                "userName":userName,
                "password":password,
                "firstName": firstName,
                "lastName": lastName,
                "homeLocationLatLong":
                {
                    "latitude": homeLocationLatLong_latitude,
                    "longitude": homeLocationLatLong_longitude
                },
                "homeLocationText": homeLocationText,
                "homePhoneNumber": homePhoneNumber,
                "cellPhoneNumber": cellPhoneNumber

            }

        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
           console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    })
```

but when i send data, i see this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://199.166.212.50:8080/.../add. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

what can i must do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. i use [this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en) and add `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this it will work for you.

```
 <script>
  $("#login_info").click(function(){
    var name = $('#username').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    var token_key =  $('input[name=_token]').val();
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '{{url("admin_panel/login/auth")}}',
       data: {
        '_token': token_key,
        'username': name,
        'password': pass
      },
       success: function(data)
       {
        alert('in_sucess');
       }
    })
});
```